# JavaFX Double (Unwanted) Event on Tab Selection

Tags: javafx, controller, tabs, listener

I have a weird bug in my JavaFX program, dealing with EventHandlers and Tabs.  I've been researching it like crazy, yet the specific solution eludes me.

Here's the skinny:  In my main controller, I have a tab pane; each tab is controlled by a nested controller.  The second tab, TabB, has a ListView of Strings in it.  Every time the user clicks TabB, I want the ListView to refresh its contents.  Here's the code in the main controller which sets up TabB:

```
@FXML   TabBController      AnchorPaneTabBController;   // Nested Controller
@FXML   Tab                 tabB;
...
AnchorPaneTabBController.setUpTabB();
// Code to detect when this tab is clicked:
tabB.setOnSelectionChanged(new EventHandler<Event>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Event t) {
        if (tabB.isSelected()) {
            AnchorPaneTabBController.refreshContent();
        }
    }
});
```

Here's the relevant code from "TabBController.java":

```
public class TabBController {

    @FXML   ListView    listViewMyStuff;

    private @FXML   void initialize() {...blah blah...}

    public void setUpTabB(){
        System.out.println("......setUpTabB()");
        // set listener for the ListView
        listViewMyStuff
            .getSelectionModel()
            .selectedIndexProperty()
            .addListener(
                (obs, oldVal, newVal) -> doStuffWithSelection(listViewMyStuff));
    }
    private void doStuffWithSelection(ListView newVal){
        String str = (String) listViewMyStuff.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println(" -- You clicked on: "+str);
    }

    public void refreshContent(){
        ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<SpaceObject>();
        ObservableList<SpaceObject> obsList;
        // put items in arrList
        obsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList( arrList );
        listViewMyStuff.setItems(obsList);
    }
}
```

To be honest, I'm not sure this is the best design.  The basic idea I had was that `setUpTabB()` would be called once by the Main Controller, and it would do all the one-time operations that TabB would need.  `refreshContent()` is called every time the user clicks TabB.  You'll note the ListView's listener is in `setUpTabB()` - this is because I want only one listener created.  (I think putting it in `refreshContent()` would create a new listener every time TabB is clicked.)

Okay... so this almost works.  Suppose the ListView is populated with two Strings, "String A", and "String B".  Further suppose I click on TabB, then click on each string in order.  Here's the output:

```
......setUpTabB()
 -- You clicked on: String A
 -- You clicked on: String B
```

So far, so good.  Now here's the bug.  Suppose I click on another tab, any tab, and then click TabB again.  The instant that happens, the output becomes:

```
......setUpTabB()
 -- You clicked on: String A
 -- You clicked on: String B
 -- You clicked on: null
 -- You clicked on: String B
```

So...  This is the weirdest thing I've seen all year.  It seems that when I click TabB the second time, the listener set up in `setUpTabB()` kicks in and... reselects nothing ***and then*** reselects my previous selection...?  I've stepped through this with the debugger, but I can't figure out what is going on here.  In fact, every time I click away then reclick TabB, the same thing happens consistently:

```
......setUpTabB()
 -- You clicked on: String A
 -- You clicked on: String B    // Now I click TabA, then TabB...
 -- You clicked on: null
 -- You clicked on: String B    // Now I click TabC, then TabB...
 -- You clicked on: null
 -- You clicked on: String B    // Now I click TabA, then TabC, then TabB...
 -- You clicked on: null
 -- You clicked on: String B
```

This beats me.  I assume the listener is still working and reselecting my previous choice when I reselect TabB.  I guess...?

Anyone ever seen something like this before?  Any advice/insight is appreciated.

Comment: You replace all the items in the list view. So that first removes everything that's there, and then replaces it with a bunch of new stuff. If something is selected when you remove everything that's there, what would you expect the selected item to change to, if not to null? This just seems like exactly the expected behavior.

Comment: @James_D ...interesting!  Your take completely didn't occur to me.  I assumed that if I removed the list's contents, the user's selection wouldn't exist from that point on out.

Answer (score 0):

James_D's comment was what I needed to clear this up.  He was right in that my code was reloading content unnecessarily.  Its a design issue.  I wound up scrapping the above code and starting again from scratch.  Thanks James_D!